# Having a Quarz.Net Job recurring every 30 minutes... works only the first time

Tags: quartz.net

I'm quite new to Quartz.Net (in the past I've set it using Cron sintax to run one time per run).

This time I need to have a recurring task that's performed every 30 minutes.

It performs only one.

Here's what I've done till now

```
 public class Core : ICore
{
    private IScheduler scheduler;
    private readonly IConfiguration configuration;
    private static readonly TimeSpan defaultInterval = new TimeSpan(0,1,0);

    public Core(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        this.configuration = configuration;
    }

    public async Task StartAsync()
    {
        var interval = configuration.GetValue("interval", defaultInterval);
        // Grab the Scheduler instance from the Factory
        NameValueCollection props = new NameValueCollection
        {
            { "quartz.serializer.type", "binary" }
        };
        StdSchedulerFactory factory = new StdSchedulerFactory(props);
        this.scheduler = await factory.GetScheduler();

        this.scheduler.JobFactory =new SimpleInjectorJobFactory(ContainerWrapper.Container, Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<RinnovoJob>()
            .WithIdentity("RinnovoJob", "sender").StoreDurably(true)
            .Build();



        ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithIdentity($"trigger_RinnovoJob", "sender")
            .StartNow().WithSimpleSchedule(x=>x.WithInterval(interval))
            .Build();

        // Tell quartz to schedule the job using our trigger
        await this.scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);

        // and start it off
        await this.scheduler.Start();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {

    }
}
```

And here's the Job

```
 public class RinnovoJob:IJob
{
    [omiss]

    public RinnovoJob([omiss])
    {
        [omiss]
    }

    public Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
      log.Info("Passed");

      return Task.CompletedTask;

    }
}
```

It writes the "Passed" just one time. I've read on the doc to set the Durability to true, as I've done using `StoreDurably(true)` but it doesn't seems to work.

Any suggestion?
Another question, is there a way I can avoid the execution of the job if there's one of the same type running?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I've managed... I was missing the `.RepeatForever()` call

Here's the working code

```
ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithIdentity($"trigger_RinnovoJob", "sender")
            .StartNow().WithSimpleSchedule(x=>x.WithInterval(interval).RepeatForever())
            .Build();
```

Hope this can help others that wasted their time in a similar situation